# different behaviour for prepareExternalUrl in angular6 vs angular5

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6

I'm trying to upgrade angular 5 to angular 6.

I have this setting for base HREF

```
NG_BASE_HREF="&#x2f;plugins/cohesis/hcp/"
```

In angular 5 this line of code would generate a valid URL

```
this.http.get(this.location.prepareExternalUrl('/../cohesis_api/hcpinfo.php?guid='+guid), {withCredentials: true})
```

namely:

`https://localhost/plugins/cohesis_api/hcpinfo.php?guid=5b3b3b3260db2`

In angular 6 it generates an invalid URL namely `https://localhost/plugins/cohesis/hcp/cohesis_api/hcpinfo.php?guid=5b3b3b3260db2`

What would be the correct way to get this relative path in angular6?